# Почему glyph-orientation-vertical не располагает текст по вертикали?

Tags: вёрстка, svg, сss3

Почему атрибут `glyph-orientation-vertical="0"` не располагает текст по вертикали?

```html
<svg width="500" height="200" viewBox="100 0 500 200" style='border: 1px solid black' >
  <text  font-size="85px" fill='red' x='50%' y='50%' text-decoration='overline underline line-through'  glyph-orientation-vertical="0"  font-weight="700">abcvvv</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибут `glyph-orientation-vertical` больше не поддерживается.

Но кроме этого в SVG и CSS есть много атрибутов, чтобы вертикально расположить текст.

Кроме того в браузерах, которые поддерживают трансформацию вращения можно повернуть текст либо на 90, либо на 270 градусов.

**В SVG writing-mode:tb;**

```css
.txt {
   font-size:60px;
   fill:red;
   text-decoration:overline underline line-through;
   font-weight:700;
  }
  .txt_R {
   font-size:60px;
   fill:dodgerblue;
   text-decoration:overline underline line-through;
   font-weight:700;
   writing-mode:tb;
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="100 0 500 200" style='border: 1px solid black' >
  <text class="txt"  x='50%' y='0'>Вертикаль</text>
  <text class="txt_R"  x='50%' y='0%'>Вертикаль</text>
 </svg>
```

**В CSS transform: rotate(270deg);**

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        h2 {
           margin: 0;
           transform: rotate(270deg);
           transform-origin: top left;
           color: #852c98;
           position: absolute;
           top: 200px;
           font-size:2em;
        }
    </style>

<h2 class="vert"> Вертикаль </h2>
</html>
```

**transform: rotate(90deg);**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        h2 {
           margin: 0;
           transform: rotate(90deg);
           transform-origin: top right;
           color: #852c98;
     font-size:2em;
           position: absolute;
           top: 200px;
        }
    </style>

<h2 class="vert"> Вертикаль </h2>
</html>
```